# Do topological spaces that have the same singular homology groups necessarily have the same singular cohomology groups?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

And what are the conditions for that to be true?

Comment: Additionally, there is more structure on cohomology called the cup product, but this is not determined by homology.

Comment: Yes! The relevant theorem is the "universal coefficient theorem for cohomology", cf theorem 2.2 in this article: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+coefficient+theorem#InCohomology

Comment: The price you pay is you must compute Ext groups of the homology groups

Answer (score 5):

@HallaSurvivor already told you the answer but we can kind of split up our question and answer it in two cases:

1. Suppose we have some isomorphism between the homology groups of two spaces, do we necessarily have some isomorphism between the cohomology groups?

Yes, like @HallaSurvivor said this is given by the fact that the universal coefficient sequence splits.

2. Suppose we have some isomorphism between homology groups that is induced by a map of spaces, does this necessarily induce an isomorphism on cohomology groups?

Yes, again we use the universal coeffecient sequence, but now we use the five lemma to deduce the middle map must be an isomorphism.

These two questions are very different as there are spaces with isomorphic homology that are not homotopy equivalent. It is actually kind of surprising that homology determines the cohomology, since we usually can't say much if the isomorphism is not determined by a map of spaces. But when you actually look at the universal coefficient theorem, you can see that the statement and proof are completely algebraic. When you interpret this in light of the fact that the homology/cohomology does not determine the cup product, you see that the cup product encodes additional topological information that purely algebraic results can't see.